# How to switch workspace in jackrabbit-standalone command line (cli)?

Tags: java, jackrabbit, jcr

How do I switch workspace in `jackrabbit-standalone` command line client? I have version `2.4.3`.

I connect like this:

```
java -jar jackrabbit-standalone-2.4.3.jar --cli rmi://localhost:1100/jackrabbit
```

It logs me as anonymous, so I switch to admin like this:

```
[/] > logout

elapsed time: 2 ms.

[not logged in] > login admin admin

elapsed time: 21 ms.

[/] > info

Repository: rmi://localhost:1100/jackrabbit
User      : admin
Workspace : default
Node      : /

Session is live.
Session has no changes.
```

How do I switch workspace from default? I couldn't find any information in `help` command. It only says how to create new workspace or how to clone or copy nodes into another workspace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `login` command. Lets get help for `login` command via `help login`:

```
[/] > help login

description:
Login to the current working Repository

usage:login <user> <password> -workspace <name>

<arguments>
name       argument   required   description
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------------------------------------
user       user       false      registered user name [default=anonymous]
password   password   false      password  [default = anonymous]

<options>
name       argument   required   description
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------------------------------------
workspace  name       false      workspace
```

So you need to login like so:

```
login admin admin -workspace anotherWorkspace
```